# Please help me understand a while condition in a binary search function

Tags: c, loops, search, while-loop

I am learning in C about sorting arrays and `while` loops. Some code from the book I'm using to study this with is the following:

```
//function to perform binary search of an array
size_t binarySearch(const int b[], int searchKey, size_t low, size_t high)
{
    //loop until low index is greater than high index
    while (low <= high) {
        
        //determine middle element of subarray being searched
        size_t middle = (low + high) / 2;

        //display subarray used in this iteration
        printRow(b, low, middle, high);

        // if searchKey matched middle element, return middle
        if (searchKey == b[middle]) {
             return middle;
        }

        // if searchKey is less than middle element, set new high
        else if (searchKey < b[middle]) {
           high = middle - 1; //search low end of array
        }

        else {
           low = middle + 1; //search high end of the array
        }
     }//end while

     return -1; //searchKey not found
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how the initial while condition works: `while (low <= high)`. I mean it seems like `low` can never be greater than `high`. Can anyone tell me under what situation `low` would be greater than `high` and therefore terminate the loop?

I tried to write down and visualize how the algorithm might work, but I cannot understand it.

Comment: Integer division error might contribute to a condition where `middle + 1` (low) is greater than `middle - 1` (high), (even though the statements assigning these values are separated by exclusive if blocks) thus satisfying the exit condition  (both `low` and `high` are dependent on `size_t middle = (low + high) / 2;`)

Comment: `low` _can_ become greater than `high` with: `low = middle + 1;`. If `low` is (e.g.) 5 and `high` is 5, then `low` becomes 6. If `if (searchKey == b[middle]) return middle;` returns we have a _match_. If we fall through to the end of the loop, the search has failed to match.

Comment: Learn to use your tool-chain's debugger, step through the code, watch the variables.  Much easier than posting on SO, and will answer thousands of other questions that will arise as you learn.  The debugger is the _second_ thing you should learn about right after "hello, world".  You will thank me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these conditions value of `low` is greater than the value of `high`

**When an element is not in the list and the element to find is greater than the element at mid:** There will be only one element in the list, so the `low = middle + 1` will execute, and the resulting value of `low` greater

**When in function call we pass high greater than low**

```
binarySearch(arr, search_value, 4, 3)
```

### Try for these inputs

**Input**

```
array = {2, 3, 4, 10, 40}
to_search = 11
```

**Output (low, high)**

```
0, 4
3, 4
4, 4
4, 3  <--- low > high
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't treat the statement as something in normal everyday talks. Of course, normally there is no discussion about any chance of having 5 being higher, than, say, 8.

But in code, loops and conditions, things are different, because code is dynamic. If you'll follow the code, among the many conditions you'll see that there is a situation of `low = middle + 1;` (that's the last condition). At the "opposite" spectrum you'll see a condition above it `high = middle - 1;`. And of course one that controls middle: `middle = (low + high) / 2;`.

In this situation, low has a chance (assuming you hit its condition) to increase and high has a chance (again, assuming you hit its condition) to decrease.

Going back to our random example at the start of 5 and 8, that means the first number might eventually go up from to 7 and 8 might go down to 4. In our code, of course, you need to follow the actual flow and see the values and how and when they hit those conditions.

But bottom line is, low and high are never static. This is a rare occasion as you'll find most loops only modifying the first variable (in our case **low **). But that is how one patter of loops is: you start off at one value or one condition, then you progress in the code until you break that condition.

Small caveat: because control flow is man-made, if one does not pay attention they might end up with infinite loops (meaning the stop condition is never triggered). That means the program will go in a loop and basically "sit still" but still use up CPU power (and, depending on what it does in the loop, even memory until the machine runs out of memory).

What you'll see in some loops as a precaution is something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (some condition)
{
    if (i++ > some number)
        break;

    ... some control flow code
}
```

What that does is a failsafe stop. a variable is incremented each loop until a number that the programmer feels is safe enough then exists the loop. `break` is how you exit loops. Of course, this is just a failsafe, as I said, normally you need to make sure that the code inside the loops are properly handled and no chance of an infinite loop happens.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that `searchKey` is not in your array to make the explanation easier. Here is an example:

- `b` is `{ 1, 2, 3 }`
- `searchKey` is `4`
- `low` is `0`
- `high` is `2`

Initially `low` is less than `high` so we enter the while loop. `middle` is `(0 + 2) / 2` which is `1`. In our particular case we hit the `else` statement which means we set `low` to `middle + 1` which is `2`. That means `low` is now equal to `high` so the loop continues. This time `middle` is `(2 + 2) / 2` which is `2`. We hit the `else` statement again setting `low` to `3` making `low` greater than `high` and ending the loop

If instead `searchKey` was `-1` then we would have set `high` to `middle - 1` which is `0`. That would have meant `high` is now equal to `low`. On the following iteration of the loop we would set `high` again with a value of `-1` ending the loop